# Efficiently render large number of polygon in World Wind

Tags: java, render, worldwind, large-data

I have very large number of polygons and I want to render them on world wind. So was I was using their Polygon class as follows:

```
        ShapeAttributes normalAttributes = new BasicShapeAttributes();

        normalAttributes.setInteriorMaterial(Material.YELLOW);
        normalAttributes.setOutlineWidth(2);
        normalAttributes.setOutlineOpacity(0.5);
        normalAttributes.setDrawInterior(true);
        normalAttributes.setDrawInterior(true);

        //define the coordinates position
        ArrayList<Position> positions = new ArrayList<Position>();
        positions.add(Position.fromDegrees(52, 10, 5e4));
        positions.add(Position.fromDegrees(55, 11, 5e4));
        positions.add(Position.fromDegrees(55, 11, 5e4));
        positions.add(Position.fromDegrees(52, 14, 5e4));
        positions.add(Position.fromDegrees(52, 10, 5e4));

        Polygon poly = new Polygon(positions);
```

It works for small data-sets, but when the number of polygons increase(~45k), It runs out of memory(4GB), or for lesser number runs slowly. Can someone suggest some technique to render such a large data-set efficiently. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that you need to simplify the number of points in the polygon. One method of doing this is using the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). Using this, you can greatly reduce the number of points within your polygon while maintaining its shape.

There are many implementations of this algorithm available, depending on licensing, including [simplify-java (MIT licence)](https://github.com/hgoebl/simplify-java).